# Grouping list of objects and reduce subgroups into different objects in Java 8

Tags: java, list, object, java-stream, transform

I have this requirement of transforming a List of Objects into List of grouped objects of different type.

```
public class Person {
private String name;
private String dept;
private int amount;
    //constructors
    //getters and setters
}


public class GroupedPersons {

private String dept;
private int sumAmount;
private List<Person> personsOfDept; 

    // how should be the constructor??
    //getters and setters
}  


List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("Mark", "Sales", 100),
            new Person("Rob", "Marketing", 200),
            new Person("Kyle", "Sales", 150),
            new Person("Jack", "Accounts", 50),
            new Person("Sam", "Sales", 150),
            new Person("Jeff", "Marketing", 200));
```

I need the result as

```
List<GroupedPersons> 

["Sales",400,List<Person>]
["Marketing",400,List<Person>]
["Accounts",50,List<Person>]
```

I tried

```
Map<String,List<Person>> deptMap = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getDept));
```

But unable to reduce the map to the List of object I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a constructor for the `GroupedPersons` class that will take the `dept`, `sumAmount` and `personsOfDept` list, like so:

```
class GroupedPersons {

    private String dept;
    private int sumAmount;
    private List<Person> personsOfDept;

    public GroupedPersons(String dept, int sumAmount, List<Person> personsOfDept) {
        this.dept = dept;
        this.sumAmount = sumAmount;
        this.personsOfDept = personsOfDept;
    }
}
```

Then we can use the the following logic to first get the grouping done by `dept` of the `Person` which will result in a `Map<String, List<Person>>` and then using the stream from the `entrySet().stream()` of the map to sum the `amount` and get the `List<Person>` from the `Map.Entry<String, List<Person>>.getValue()`:

```
 List<GroupedPersons> list = persons.stream()
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getDept()))
                                    .entrySet()
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(ent -> new GroupedPersons(
                                                ent.getKey(),
                                  ent.getValue().stream().mapToInt(p -> p.getAmount()).sum(),
                                                ent.getValue()))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Fragments like `p -> p.getDepth()` should be replaced with `Person::getDepth` for better readability. Same for `p -> p.getAmount()`.

Comment: how can we do the sum in the constructor argument if sumAmount is of type BigInteger..as .sum() is not available