# How to group and reduce a list of objects with duration

Tags: java, java-stream, java-time, duration, localdate

I want to create a list of persons sorted by `LocalDate` and `String` as well as aggregated by duration.

I did some research regarding the use of duration in streams:

- [How to get the average duration for each category having films using stream API java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70606831/how-to-get-the-average-duration-for-each-category-having-films-using-stream-api)
- [Using streams to sum a collection of immutable `Duration` objects, in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60816247/using-streams-to-sum-a-collection-of-immutable-duration-objects-in-java)

and on using streams with grouping and reducing a list of objects into subgroups:

- [Grouping list of objects and reduce subgroups into different objects in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57337508/grouping-list-of-objects-and-reduce-subgroups-into-different-objects-in-java-8)

However, it's impossible for me to solve my problem, class `Person` looks like this:

```java
class Person { 
    private LocalDate startDate; 
    private String personType;
    private Duration time1;
    private Duration time2;//constructor, getter+setter, other methods
}
```

An example of the created list looks like this:

```
List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(
          new Person("2023-02-02","member1","08:00","4:00"),
        new Person("2023-02-02","member1","50:00","0:45"),  
        new Person("2023-02-02","member2","10:00","0:40"),
        new Person("2023-02-02","member2","01:00","1:20"),
        new Person("2023-02-03","member1","08:00","2:00"),
        new Person("2023-02-03","member1","10:00","0:45"),  
        new Person("2023-02-03","member2","10:00","1:40"),
        new Person("2023-02-03","member2","02:00","1:20"),//... 
 );
```

I want to create a list of persons sorted by startdate and personType, with the sum of duration.

Desired output:

```
("2023-02-02","member1","58:00","4:45"),
("2023-02-02","member2","11:00","2:00"),
("2023-02-03","member1","18:00","2:45"),
("2023-02-03","member2","12:00","3:00"),
...
```

My approach is to use something like this. However, I can't map duration and string values:

```
Map<LocalDate,List<Person>> result=personList.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getstartDate))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> {
            //how to sum duration values in here?
           // Duration duration1 = x.getValue().stream() ...;
            //how to use String values in here?
           // String string = x.getValue().stream()....
            return new Person(x.getKey(), string, duration1,duration2);
        }, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: You showed a list of people as your expected result, but you are collecting to a `Map`? Which one do you want exactly?

Comment: Do you want the sum of all durations for each member for each date? And why are you instantiating a `Person` with `new Item(…)`?

Comment: As a result I want a list of persons. It is my understanding that I need a map for that. if a have all the results in map, I can create a list again. However if its possible without a map, that would be better.

Comment: As for the  provided example with "new item": this is just  to demonstrate the "layout" of each person-list-object.

Comment: The first argument to the `toMap` collector is for the *key*, so its not the right place for trying to sum values. The second function determines the value, but only the single value  of a single element, so it isn’t the right place either. For aggregating multiple values, a *third* argument has to be specified. The function specified as third argument will receive two values and allows you to insert your summation.

Comment: By the way… Standard format for duration text is [defined in ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. Ex: `PT8H` vs `08:00`.

Comment: Your result is *not* a list a persons. You have duplicates, with "member1" and "member2" both listed multiple times. What you really have is a flattened hierarchy of date -> person.

Comment: Why padding zero on your `time1` inputs but not `time2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with a cascade of groupings and a reduction to sum the durations. The following results in a 2-level map that contains the sum per date and type:

```java
Map<LocalDate, Map<String, Optional<Person>>> perDateAndTypeAggregated = 
    personList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Person::getStartDate,
        Collectors.groupingBy(
                Person::getType,
                Collectors.reducing((p1, p2) ->
                    // this is where we sum the durations
                    new Person(p1.getStartDate(), p1.getType(), p1.getTime1().plus(p2.getTime1()), p1.getTime2().plus(p2.getTime2()))
                )
        )
    ));
```

If you want a list (the map gives richer information, but it's your application), you can flatten and sort the previous map as follows:

```java
Comparator<Person> byDateThenType =
    Comparator.comparing(Person::getStartDate).thenComparing(Person::getType);

List<Person> result =
    perDateAndTypeAggregated.values().stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .sorted(byDateThenType)
        .toList();
```

---

**EDIT:** As per the comments from Holger, the above can be simplified using `toMap` instead of the `groupingBy`/`reducing` combination, with the added advantage of simplifying the second operation (`toList`) by removing the `.filter().map()` combo:

```java
Map<LocalDate, Map<String, Person>> perDateAndTypeAggregated2 = 
    personList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Person::getStartDate,
        Collectors.toMap(
                Person::getType,
                Function.identity(),
                (p1, p2) ->
                    // this is where we sum the durations
                    new Person(p1.getStartDate(), p1.getType(), p1.getTime1().plus(p2.getTime1()), p1.getTime2().plus(p2.getTime2()))
        )
    ));

List<Person> result2 =
    perDateAndTypeAggregated2.values().stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
        .sorted(byDateThenType)
        .toList();
```

---

**EDIT 2:** I used the following `Person` class:

```java
public static class Person {
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private String type;
    private Duration time1;
    private Duration time2;

    public Person() {}

    public Person(String startDate, String type, String time1, String time2) {
        this.startDate = LocalDate.parse(startDate);
        this.type = type;
        this.time1 = Duration.parse(time1);
        this.time2 = Duration.parse(time2);
    }

    public Person(LocalDate startDate, String type, Duration time1, Duration time2) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.type = type;
        this.time1 = time1;
        this.time2 = time2;
    }

    // getters and setters...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person(" + startDate + "," + type + "," + time1 + "," + time2 + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Person person = (Person) o;
        return Objects.equals(startDate, person.startDate) && Objects.equals(type, person.type) && Objects.equals(time1, person.time1) && Objects.equals(time2, person.time2);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(startDate, type, time1, time2);
    }
}
```

And initialize the list as:

```java
List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(
        new Person("2023-02-02","member1","PT8H00M","PT4H00M"),
        new Person("2023-02-02","member1","PT50H00M","PT0H45M"),
        new Person("2023-02-02","member2","PT10H00M","PT0H40M"),
        new Person("2023-02-02","member2","PT1H00M","PT1H20M"),
        new Person("2023-02-03","member1","PT8H00M","PT2H00M"),
        new Person("2023-02-03","member1","PT10H00M","PT0H45M"),
        new Person("2023-02-03","member2","PT10H00M","PT1H40M"),
        new Person("2023-02-03","member2","PT2H00M","PT1H20M")
);
```

All this code is giving me the desired outcome from the question.

Comment: When you use `toMap` instead of `groupingBy`+`reducing`, you don’t need those `.filter(Optional::isPresent) .map(Optional::get)` steps.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It looks like I have to spend more time to understand the possibilities of java stream.api

Comment: @Holger The filter/map step is ugly, but is a result of using the simple form of `reducing​(BinaryOperator)`. This IMO makes the grouping/reducing step a bit less complex, at the expense of an uglier sort/toList step. If I used `reducing​(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> op)` the filter/map would no longer be needed, at the expense of more complicated code in the grouping/reducing operation. I am not sure how `toMap` would help, but I would be interested in an example.

Comment: Instead of `Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getType, Collectors.reducing((p1, p2) -> …))` you simply use `Collectors.toMap(Person::getType, Function.identity(), (p1, p2) -> …)` The merge function is identical to your reduction function. Then, the result would be `Map<String, Person>` instead of `Map<String, Optional<Person>>`. See also [Replacing groupingBy and reducing by toMap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57041896/2711488)

Comment: Hey @Holger yeah, great idea, thanks! I thought you meant replacing the *first* `groupingBy` - that confused me; replacing the *second*, as you made clear in your comment, makes perfect sense. I will add it to the answer!

Comment: Indeed, the first `groupingBy` can not be replaced that way, but it could be fused into the second, when using a compound key, e.g. `record Key(LocalDate date, String type) {}` … `Map<Key, Person> map = … .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> new Key(p.getStartDate(), p.getType()), Function.identity(), (p1, p2) -> …));` Then, no flattening is needed: `List<Person> result = new ArrayList<>(map.values()); result.sort(byDateThenType);` There are pros and cons to this approach…

Comment: Yes again: I thought of using a compound key, but preferred to keep things simple (even naive if you want) instead of the extra effort of a complex key. But, exactly as you say, there are pros and cons and a matter of taste if I may add!

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos: really appreciate your work! Thank you very much! I was wondering if its possible to add a second grouping by criteria to the function (in this case the string value)?
I am asking, because I have a list with some kind of time stamps which I want to query in different ways.

Comment: Not sure I understand, can you edit the question giving an example?

Comment: Your solution aggregates all values of a specific person - in this case "member1" for each LocalDate. It does not aggregate values for "member2" for each localDate.
Example of my desired output:
//Day 1
("2023-02-02","member1","58:00","4:45"), //-> output of your solution
("2023-02-02","member2","11:00","2:00"), //-> not included
//Day 2
("2023-02-03","member1","18:00","2:45"),
("2023-02-03","member2","12:00","3:00");
//…
So I was wondering if it is possible to add a grouping by person-getType in such a way that the output considers both person-Types?

Comment: When I run it, I get the same outcome as the one from the question, i.e. *("2023-02-02","member2","11:00","2:00")*. I included the `Person` class I used in the answer.